# ISO Fails to Burn in K3B

Tags: 12.04, dvd, burning, k3b

I was trying to burn Zorin OS 6.4 LTS on to a DVD+R disc, so that I could have it on my laptop.

Anyway, it started to burn it, but it failed and ejected the disc.

Here's what it said in the status bar-thingy:

```
Writing Double-Layer DVD+R
Using Wodim 1.1.11 Copyright (C) 2006 Cdrkit Suite Contributors
Starting at 1x Speed
Unable to open a new session
Probably a problem with the medium
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your DVD was not new/empty. I'd suggest to try with a new disc. As a "plan B" I'd use an USB to make a bootable USB (using Unetbootin) in order to install the new OS.